# Fix: ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'

Tags: brownie

This error seems to come up to several people doing Patrick Collins' freeCodeCamp tutorial. Just thought I'd give you the answer I finally found.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, simply run `source .env` in the terminal, and that should do it.

If this does not fix it, make sure the files `brownie-config.yaml` and `.env` is in the correct place (root directory of the project).